# url should not change on submitting a form

Tags: django

i have this Django application in which when user request for "localhost:8000/time/ ,it is shown html form input.html.

```
<head>

<!-- paste this in your footer -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myForm').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                type: $(this).attr('POST'), // "post"
                url: $(this).attr('/poi/'), //  "/poi/"
                success: function(response) { 
                    // do something here
                }
            });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<!-- add jquery or it won't work -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <form action="/poi/" method = "post">

        <!---------
        first name :<input type ="text" name ="fname">
        last name:<input type ="text" name ="lname">
        ------>

        enter a days :<input type ="text" name ="days">
        <br>
        <input type=submit name="submit" onclick="submit_function(); return false;">
        </form>

</body>
```

when form is submitted user sees response.html page and URL is changed to  "localhost:8000/poi/ is shown having

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                            (r'^hello/$', hello),   
                            ('^time/$', current_datetime),
                            ('^poi/$', next_datetime),

                        )
```

views.py

```
def current_datetime(request):  
    return render_to_response('input.html')


def next_datetime(request):

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    now_day = now.day
    now_month = now.month
    now_year = now.year

    return render_to_response('response.html', {'now_day': now_day, 'now_month'}}
```

now i have to do same thing but the url should not change from "localhost:8000/time/  to "localhost:8000/poi/ 
but it should be "localhost:8000/time/

how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ajax to accomplish this
With jquery it would look something like

```
<form id="myForm"> ... </form> <!-- add an id to your form -->

<!-- paste this in your footer -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myForm').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                type: $(this).attr('method'), // "post"
                url: $(this).attr('action'), //  "/poi/"
                success: function(response) { 
                    // do something here
                }
            });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<!-- add jquery or it won't work -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and it should work out of the box

this is with an anonymous function, but you can put the code inside a named one and then add it to the button:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="submit_function(); return false;" />
```

it's basically the same

Comment: i am novice to javascript/ajax acould you explain more. what changes exactly i have to do and in which files/

Comment: i edited my post with a little bit more of information so you may understand :)

Comment: what should be the method in attr('method') and action in attr('action') ?

Comment: you can hardcode them to "POST" (or "GET") and your action ("/poi/") but that $(this).attr(...) means: take "this" object (which is "myForm", if everything went as expected) and get his attribute (.attr()) whose name is the string inside the parenthesis (.attr("action"), .attr("method") and so on...)

Comment: in input.html i have placed this code outside <body</body> and set attr('POST') and action in attr('/poi/'). what should be myForm in $('#myForm').submit(function())

Comment: i suggest you to read http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_howto.asp . script should always be placed inside your footer (so the page can full load and display, and only then load the scripts) or in your <head></head>. Also a tip for when you ask: don't ask for a full step-by-step, try out your code and keep editing the original question (marking clearly the edited section). you risk loosing nice answers if you keep going via comments ;)